# how to install other operation systems without live cd

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

recently i have problem that not letting me installing windows 7 or even windows xp on my laptop . it always end up with bsod .

[image]

i try from dvd disk and pendisk . try to changes the iso source but still getting the same results . only able to use ubuntu. im hoping that someone can help me to figure this out .

where is the mistake and wwhat is the problem i been searching goggling and being dizzy because of lot different information

what was on my mind is since i cant do many things only using ubuntu , so i try to say ,, is it possible to make windows partitions from ubuntu ? and when you reboot it .. there is windows and ubuntu in your screen . is it ? if so how , help me . thanks you very much .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Use GParted to create NTFS partitions, which are used by default on Windows installations. You will still need to run the Windows installer from USB, DVD or CD though.

You can try searching for alternative software that allows you to do just the same thing on Ubuntu.

Other solution:
Try installing Windows inside VirtualBox, a way to make a "virtual" computer, a computer inside a computer. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

The [manual of VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html) might be helpful.

Good luck.

Comment: i did , can you assist me to make windows 7 bootable on pendisk ?

Comment: If you have a ISO file, it's simple: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool#installation

Comment: If you have a DVD and you want to make a ISO from the DVD in order to put that on a USB, have a look at http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Images-Utils/CD2ISO.shtml